# How to get access to DJI mobile UX SDK FPVWidget?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I'm using Android UX SDK 4.13 with MAVIC_2_ENTERPRISE.
My goal is to access the FPV stream via the TextureView.
Im failing to find the id of the FPVwidget that is required by the following line:

```
TextureView videostreamPreviewTtView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.XXX);
```

In the UXSDK this is the activity layout:

```
<dji.ux.widget.FPVWidget
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I tried to add Id in the activity but the setSurfaceTextureListener did not invoked the onSurfaceTextureAvailable.

How can I get reference to the FPV widget?

Comment: This is not a "DJI mobile UX SDK FPVWidget"-related question, but just a general-purpose android widget question

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the id to the UX-SDK layout:

```
<dji.ux.widget.FPVWidget
    android:id="@+id/FPVWidgetObj"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

With the new id I managed to gain access to the object:

```
TextureView videostreamPreviewTtView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.FPVWidgetObh);
```

The actual bitmap was retrieved with the following command:

```
Bitmap bitmap = videostreamPreviewTtView.getBitmap();
```